# How do I package all of my binaries in bazel?

Tags: binary, directory, packaging, bazel

There is a plethora of BUILD files scattered throughout the hierarchy of my mono repo.
Some of these files contain `cc_binary` rules.
I know they are all built into `bazel-bin`, but I'd like to get easy access to them all.
How can I package them all up, and put them all into `~/.bin/` for example?

I see the [packaging rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/pkg.html), but its not clear to me how to write a rule that captures every single program and packages them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the most elegant solution (plus I hope I got the question), but this is how we do it by packaging/"tarring" each binary in its own bazel package / `BUILD` file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello"
    ...
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")
pkg_tar(
    name = "hello_pkg",
    srcs = [":hello"],
    mode = "0755",
    package_dir = "/usr/bin",
)
```

And then we'd collect all those into a one overall tarball/package in project root:

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "mypkg",
    extension = "tar.gz",
    deps = [
        "//hello:hello_pkg",
        ...
    ],
)
```

Sometimes we'd actually have multiple such rules for hello to collect for instance executables under `bin` and libraries in `lib` with intermediary `hello_bin` and `hello_lib` targets. Which would in the same fashion as `mypkg` above be first aggregated into `hello_pkg` and that in turn would be used in `mypkg`.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the best way.  It makes it hard to impossible for quick iteration.  I was hoping to change code, rebuild, and then run the updated system tool from outside the repo.  At least for iteration, I'll have to figure out how to use `bazel run` effectively.

Comment: Indeed for that use case, `bazel run` is quite probably what you want. Even though unless you change the layout a lot, this would mostly be a one time effort and yes a some (depending on project) extra machine time + storage.